# Why is Fetch working but Apollo-Fetch is not? (calling a GraphQL API)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, graphql

I'm trying to call a GraphQL API that is in AWS Api Gateway. The call requires an x-api-key in the header to work.

I've successfully made this call in postman and using fetch.

```
fetch('ApiEndPoint', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { 
      'x-api-key': 'myApiKey' 
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({query:'{getBook(book_id:"221"){author}}'}),
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

When I try to use the Apollo-Fetch query below, I get a 403 status and "Missing Authentication Token"

```
const { createApolloFetch } = require('apollo-fetch')
const uri = 'ApiEndPoint'
const query = `{getBook(book_id:"221"){author}}`
const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch({ uri })

apolloFetch.use(({ request, options }, next) => {
  options.headers = { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'x-api-key': 'myApiKey'
  }
  next()
})

apolloFetch({ query, options }).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

I am assuming that I am not passing the x-api-key properly - if this could work better for a different GraphQL Client I would love other suggestions!